# Staring Rails App With Postgresql - PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I Cannot get the welcome screen not matter what I do, all I get is the connection issue with the postgres db error.

I ran this command to start the app.
rails new -T appName --database=postgresql

Here is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
   adapter: postgresql   
   encoding: unicode   
   pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %> 
development:   
   adapter: postgresql   
   encoding: unicode   
   database: dbname   
   pool: 5   
   username: toolshiring   
   password: toolshiring   
   host: localhost   
   port: 5432 
production:   
   <<: *default   
   database: toolshiring
   username: toolshiring   
   password: <%= ENV['toolshiring'] %>
```

I used pgAdmin to add a user with full permissions named toolshiring and has the same password.  Then created the database with owner toolshiring.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try something and it seems to have worked for the time being.

I decided to reset the password for the default db 'postgres' to the password 'postgres' as well, and delete the new db that I created....because the wasn't working for some reason.

in my database.yml file i commented everything but this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  host: localhost
```